# Cache button and bake button missing in fluid

Tags: interface, edit-mode, physics, fluid-simulation, fire

[[image: No bake button 1]

Bake button is missing in fluid panel. Other tutorials said to change the cache settings, but that too is missing!
The picture is fully scrolled, there are no more options
How to bake?

Comment: are you not supposed to bake the domain? also, in the domain, the Bake button will only appear if you select Cache > Type > All (or if you select Modular and in this case it will be in the different subpanels of the domain panel). At least it works this way for liquids.

Answer (score 2):

You have set this to a type “flow” fluid object. The flow objects go inside the “domain” fluid object, which has the cache. Flow objects cannot do anything without the domain.